# cardview is not wrapping the content inside swipeview

Tags: android, android-layout

I Want to display an listview inside an Cardview.

This is the Code I used :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/list_layout_with_fab_list_view_card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_layout_with_fab_list_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                android:outlineProvider="none" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If i remove the SwipeView the CardView is wrapping the content. but i need both swipeview as well as CardView.

Is there anything i have done wrong??

Answer (score -1):

You want to wrap a content inside cardview make sure that your card view height should set to height which is able to handle the content inside just give height in numbers and check weather it handles your content or not.Use this code in your layout and check if it works or not and in @dimes/fab_margin you can set the height for your cardview.

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">             
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/fab_margin"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="6dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    >

                    <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/listView">
                </ListView>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, Its woked for me.

Comment: @Vignesh you can vote my answer or mark tick because i am new to stackoverflow which will help me in improving my skills. ! and you welcome.